# Golang templates fails using relative paths

Tags: templates, go, go-templates, errortemplate

I just don't understand Go templates and relative paths...

Using the following directory structure:

```
Application Directory
  program.go
  program executable
-- css
     program.css
-- pages
     index.gohtml
     wartree.gohtml
```

At this point, my templates are pure html that has been in use in different environments for several years.

I have the following Go code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "html/template"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", index)
    http.HandleFunc("/wartree", wartree)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}


func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("Index has been called...")

    tmpl := template.Must(template.ParseGlob("pages/*"))
    tmpl.Execute(w, nil)
}

func wartree(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("wartree has been called...")

    tmpl := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("wartree.gohtml"))
    tmpl.Execute(w, nil)
}
```

Both templates have the following line in the HTML template heads...`<link href="css/nav.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />`

When I execute the program, the css is not used and I cannot call the Wartree template.  It just calls index again???

I even tried changing the path to the css to be absolute but that made no difference, and I see no errors from Go or the browser.

I just simply don't get Go templates and paths. I guess.

Comment: Are you serving the css files somewhere ? Something like `http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("css/")))`

Comment: @Tigger you've only set up your server to *handle* two paths `"/"` and `"/wartree"` and non of the respective handler functions (index and wartree) serve your css files. So when your server receives a request for the /css/nav.css it does not handle it, because you didn't tell it how.

Comment: @Tigger relative paths are resolved from the executable's working directory. So your `wartree` handler will have a hard time finding the template file `"wartree.gohtml"` if you execute your program from `./ApplicationDirecotry` while the html file lives in the `pages/` subdirectory. You should in that case use `"pages/wartree.gohtml"`.

Comment: @Tigger and last but not least; you're not checking any errors, that is a major no-no when using Go and it also suggests that you haven't taken the [Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) or read any of the very readable documentations. Please do so.